# Show Combo chart using json

Tags: php, mysql, json, google-visualization

I am trying to make a google ComboChart using data from json. the query that I am using is working fine in sql engine but the chart is not displaying.

**This is the google chart script:**

```
<div id="ranking_panel">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              function drawVisualization() {
                // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
                var json = $.ajax({
                            url: 'get_json_rank.php',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            async: false
                        }).responseText;
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);
                var options = {
                  title : 'Restaurant Ranking Stats',
                  vAxis: {title: "Business Growth"},
                  hAxis: {title: "Restaurants"},
                  seriesType: "bars",
                  series: {1: {type: "line"}}
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('rank_chart'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
              }
              google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
            </script>
            <div id="rank_chart"></div>
        </div>
```

**This is json code**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Error connecting to server');
mysql_select_db('db_MarkitBerry', $con);

$query = mysql_query('SELECT r_name, priority FROM tbl_restro ORDER BY priority DESC');
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Priority', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Restaurants', 'type' => 'string')
);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $temp = array();
    // each column needs to have data inserted via the $temp array
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['priority']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['r_name']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['r_name']);  
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}    
$table['rows'] = $rows;    
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);    
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');    
echo $jsonTable;
?>
```

Comment: Debug your code. Open the developer tools and look at the console, check for any Javascript errors. Look at the network tab, is your ajax request coming through alright?

Answer (score 0):

Debug!

From php/json side - use 'pre' tags and print_r function to see what is output via your request. Alternatively, install Firebug extension in Firefox, go to Network tab and set it to record every request - open the page, it will make ajax request - scroll down and see what is response.

In Javascript part, which calls up Google API - use console.log, and also use Firebug extension to see what is stored in every variable.

```
function drawVisualization() {
    // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
    var json = $.ajax({
                        url: 'get_json_rank.php',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        async: false
                    }).responseText;
    **console.log(json);**
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);
    **console.log(data);**
    var options = {
        title : 'Restaurant Ranking Stats',
        vAxis: {title: "Business Growth"},
        hAxis: {title: "Restaurants"},
        seriesType: "bars",
        series: {1: {type: "line"}}
    };              
    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('rank_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.  First, you create two columns in your DataTable, but add three columns of data (though the third is a duplicate, and so it may just have been a copy error):

```
$temp[] = array('v' => $r['priority']);
$temp[] = array('v' => $r['r_name']);
$temp[] = array('v' => $r['r_name']); // <-- this is a duplicate, either add a third column or delete this line
```

Your second problem is that you are setting both column types to `'string'`, and most charts (including everything you can build with a ComboChart) require at least one `'number'` column.  Typically, you can build a chart with the first (domain) column as a string type, but all others must be number types.